# How sample size affect the chance to reject null hypothesis in ANOVA?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, f-distribution

I am reading a book about the introduction to statistics. One chapter is about ANOVA, F distribution, and the null hypothesis. In ANOVA, the F value is

$$
  F = \frac{\text{SSB}/(k-1)}{\text{SSW}/(n-k)}
$$
where SSB is the sum of squared between groups and SSW is the sum of squared within groups while there are total n samples and k groups. The degree of freedom for between-group is df1=k-1 and the degree of freedom for within groups is df2=n-k.

It is said in the book that when the significance level $\alpha$, df1, df2 are given, the F distribution could give a critical F value (Fc), and if F>Fc, the null hypothesis is rejected.

Let's consider 3 groups (k=3 or df1=2), and $\alpha=0.05$, the Fc corresponding to df2=10, df2=100, df3=1000 are 4.1028, 3.0873 and 3.0047 separately. I am not sure if I understand it correctly but since df2 is depending on the sample size (n) while k is constant, so does it mean if we have more samples, it is easier to reject the null hypothesis? I don't quite follow it. Let's say I did 2 experiments, 3 groups. The first experiment I collected 10 samples, I got Fc value to be 4.1028, F= 3.65 so I accept the null hypothesis. Later I did the same experiment but I collect 100 samples, now Fc is 3.0873 and which will reject the null hypothesis. It is confusing and I don't understand why more samples will lead to a harsher critical value. If this is true, does it mean more samples will make it harder to accept the null hypothesis?

Comment: Is the null hypothesis true or false? (I realize you don’t know the answer to this question when you do real empirical work, but you have to make some kind of assumption about it to talk about power.) // You might just be being loose with your language when you write about accepting the null hypothesis, but there are major issues with such an idea.

Comment: Thanks @Dave I may not read very deep into the statistics yet. So far as I can tell from the books, ANOVA assumes the null hypothesis to "all groups has no difference in the mean", or may be ANOVA could also assume the mean has difference in the null hypothesis?

Comment: Yes, the standard null hypothesis in ANOVA is that all groups have equal means. When you discuss increasing the sample size, do you want to assume that to be true or false? How the power reacts to changes in sample size will depend on that. In particular, if the null hypothesis is true, power will not be affected, while power will increase if the null hypothesis is false.

Comment: Thanks @Dave I think I am not reading deep enough, so what does power mean here? Where I could get more information about it?